# Combine Worksheets Into New Workbook Based on Criteria and Save

Tags: vba, excel, extract

I have a workbook made up with 100+ worksheets. These worksheets have account number/names/days in the name of the worksheet.

The naming convention for the worksheets follows this pattern of AccountNumber/AccountName/Description:

```
11-Greg-Monday
11-Greg-Tuesday
11-Greg-Friday
38-Rachel-Sunday
38-Rachel-Tuesday
38-Rachel-Saturday
```

I would like Excel to loop through all the worksheets, and extract all of the 11-Greg worksheets and save into a new workbook named 11-Greg, and then do the same for 38-Rachel, etc.  I have a list of the account numbers/names on a worksheet named "Accounts" in the workbook.

Would it be possible to maintain the formulas after the extract of the worksheets, and formatting like column widths?

I found this code that might work to start, but I don't know how to reference the list on the "Accounts" tab to loop through for the account names?

```
Dim wb as Workbook, sht as WorkSheet
Dim strFileName As String

'Copy sheet as a new workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)

'SaveAs
strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(wb.Name) & "xlsx"
If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub 'User Canceled
wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a list of the names you want to stack on a separate list. set that list as a range and then loop through each cell checking to see if the x letters of the sheet name match. something like this

```
   Sub stacksheets()
Dim rng As Range, cCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim shName As String

Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("list").Range("a1:a2") ''this would be the list of names
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook ''remembering activeworkbook so can return


For Each cCell In rng
    shName = Left(cCell.Value, 5) ''this needs to be the minimum letters from each name that is unique
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
        If InStr(ws.Name, shName) > 0 Then ''checks for name in sheet name
            ws.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(1)
            wb2.Activate
        End If
    Next ws
    wb.SaveAs (wb2.Path & "\" & cCell.Value) '' saves workbook as list name

Next cCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you David!  This is great!